# Looking for a support portal where users have a dedicated rep

Tags: looking-for-a-script, customer-service, crm

I'm looking for a (hopefully) hosted app that would let me have my customers interact with customer support; but unlike Assistly or any of the million help desk apps out there, each user will have a dedicated rep.  When they log in, I want them to see their rep's picture, email, phone number right on the side of the page, and all the interaction will be directly between the customer and their rep.  FAQ, general CMS, etc are all fine as bonuses, but not the most important thing.

Anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't zendesk do this? When I open a ticket at chargify.com I receive the ticket email. I then get an email letting me know who (which rep) my ticket was assigned to.

When I get a response or check my ticket to add or reply to, on the right hand side I see the image (avatar) of my rep and his name.

When my rep answers my questions in his signature he includes his twitter name.

Doesn't this satisfy your need? Plus with zendesk they now generate tickets from phone calls automatically which is pretty sweet.